# Как запустить Scene Builder напрямую из Eclipse?

Tags: javafx, eclipse, java, fxml

У меня проблема: не получается запустить .fxml-файл через "Open with SceneBuilder" в Eclipse, чтобы отобразить в Scene Builder.

Подключал разные JDK: 8(u171), 9.0.1, 10.0.1, ничего не сработало.

Устанавливал путь к Scene Builder.exe в Preferences>JavaFx>SceneBuilder executable, скачивал 8 и 9ю верcии Scene Builder'а.
При нажатии на "Open with SceneBuilder" отображает ошибку "Could not open. Open operation has failed. Make sure that the choosen file is a valid FXML document." Если посмотреть "Shоw details":

```
java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.glue.GlueLoader.load(GlueLoader.java:93)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.glue.GlueLoader.load(GlueLoader.java:76)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.glue.GlueDocument.<init>(GlueDocument.java:54)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:79)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:102)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2540)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:761)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:386)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:658)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.access$100(SceneBuilderApp.java:97)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp$1.invalidated(SceneBuilderApp.java:510)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:136)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.UserLibrary.lambda$updateFirstExplorationCompleted$6(UserLibrary.java:352)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:399)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:326)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1471)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:962)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:601)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:531)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:885)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:821)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.glue.GlueLoader.load(GlueLoader.java:91)
    ... 24 more
```

Пробовал без Eclipse создавать и наполнять файл, открывать тоже без него. Если через drag-and-drop перенести файл из Eclipse в окно SceneBuilder-a, то тогда работает и можно редактировать .fxml файл напрямую в SceneBuilder-е.
Если после этого сохранить файл, то фрейм отобразиться. В чем может быть проблема?

Получилось частично решить проблему установкой более старой версии 2.0 -[здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33970132/javafx-fxml-loadexception-invalid-property), а как быть на новых версиях?

Comment: Похоже, что-то пишет (или изначально записало) некорректный XML в файл шаблона сцены. Новые версии не могут распарсить файл и вылетают. Костыль: Перегоняем все шаблоны в новый вид (тем методом, что описали выше), сохраняем, а дальше спокойно открываем через эклипсовскую обвязку для запуска билдера сцен.

Comment: @DimXenon, если вы имеете ввиду старую версию Builder-a, то на версии Scene Builder 2.0 у меня все нормально запускается. Без проблем могу  редактировать и сохранять файл с расширением fxml, дабы потом в самом eclipse продолжать писать код. На новых версиях одна и та же проблема вылазит - окно с ошибкой "Could not open. Open operation has failed. Make sure that the choosen file is a valid FXML document.".

Comment: @DimXenon, перепробовал все JDK, указал все пути, но проблему так и не решил полноценно, т.к. запускать приходится не из eclipse, а сначала открывать Builder, туда перетягивать файл fxml и лишь тогда наполнять элементами.
Конечно, если я уже потом наполню файл и сохраню в том же 8 или 9 Builder-е, то .fxml-файл измениться в eclipse, но постоянно перетягивать - неудобно.

Comment: Я к тому, что эклипс, похоже, сам уродует xml в файлах шаблонов. Правильно я понимаю: 1) Создаём шаблон в эклипсе - билдер 8 не открывает, эклипс открывает; 2) Создаём шаблон в билдер 2 - билдер 8 открывает, эклипс открывает. 3) Создаём шаблон в билдер 8 - билдер 2 и 8 открывают, эклипс открывают? Если всё верно - значит делаем шаблоны строго в билдере, а эклипс только для прописывания логики и сборки применяем.

Comment: И, если я правильно понял, проблема же в запуске билдера из эклипс? Проблема состоит в том, что билдер не запускается из эклипс в принципе, или в том, что запущенный из эклипса билдер не открывает файл шаблона, который при обычном запуске билдера открывается корректно?

Comment: @DimXenon, при использовании билдера 8, эклипс шаблон не открывается в принципе из эклипс.
При использовании билдера 9 вылетает ошибка, а при 2.0 нет ошибок вообще.

Comment: Когда у меня не открывается билдер, в простыне ошибок он указывает строку, которая ему не понравилась. Но тут я не вижу чего-то подобного.